# What is the correct way to obtain an asynchronous resource in the mapping of some data?

Tags: angular, rxjs

From the following data set I am trying to replace the value of the logoUrl property which is a protected blob resource in S3 with a value that I can use in the template

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ABC",
    logoUrl: null,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "DEF",
    logoUrl:
      "https://assets.demo.app.net/bucket/154F460F8FAE344F13C29962931CBD3C1F1384F7A9DF9F548D23CF4AFF5E6811-some-name.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "GHI",
    logoUrl:
      "https://assets.demo.app.net/bucket/4CA2F69627B51F7F07A39642DB3538A3D55564891F456528067B47DCEED61B4F-some-name.png",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "JKL",
    logoUrl: null,
  },
];
```

To this end I try to implement the following Resolve

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FetchDataResolver implements Resolve<Model[]> {
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private s3Service: S3Service
  ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<Model[]> {
    return this.dataService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(
        map((data) => data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)))
      );
  }
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is how inside `.pipe()` Could I map the response of getting the resource from `S3` and then replace the record. Because the first action is an asynchronous operation.

The S3 service has two methods, one is responsible for obtaining the resource that is a blob and the second is responsible for obtaining a url that I can use in the template to display the image. The service is as follows

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class S3Service {
  constructor(
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}

  getResource(resource: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.get(resource, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }

  getSourceFromBlob(blob: Blob): SafeUrl {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }
}
```

The expected result is similar to the following

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ABC",
    logoUrl: null,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "DEF",
    logoUrl:
      "blob:http://localhost:4200/e9113189-d08e-485c-b61a-5a8f5f4a0fdd",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "GHI",
    logoUrl:
      "blob:http://localhost:4200/e9113189-d08e-485c-b61a-5a8f5f4a0fdd",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "JKL",
    logoUrl: null,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to get a high level picture of the situation.

You've a got a stream, that gives you an `Observable<Model[]>`.

From that stream, you want to get a new stream that has the exact same shape but where 1 property has been updated (`logoUrl`).

In order to do that, you need to make an asynchronous action for **each item of the array.**

When that's the case, pretty much the first operator to think about it [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin). That operator let's you pass an array of observables and will give you back one stream containing all the arrays. So in other words: Pass an `Array<Observable<T>>` and you'll get back `Observable<Array<T>>`.

If you're having a hard time thinking about that one and you're familiar with `Promise.all` it's very much alike.

```
return this.dataService.getAll().pipe(
  map((data) => data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))),
  switchMap((data) => {
    // for each entry...
    const dataWithSourceLogoUrl$ = data.map((x) => {
      this.s3Service
      // let's fetch the source logo
        .getSourceFromBlob(x.logoUrl)
        // and merge it back to the original object
        .pipe(pipe(map((sourceLogoUrl) => ({ ...x, logoUrl: sourceLogoUrl }))));
    });
    
    // finally, use forkJoin to start all the streams we prepared above
    return forkJoin(dataWithSourceLogoUrl$);
  })
);
```

Hopefully the comments in the code are enough but if it's not let me know and I'll edit to explain more.